# How to Remove the particular array value not an object?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

*This is the value my array contains:*

```
(
        {
        yes = 0;
    },
        {
        yes = 1;
    },
        {
        yes = 2;
    },
        {
        yes = 3;
    },
        {
        yes = 4;
    }
)
```

Now i like to remove yes=1;

*this is My code*

```
-(void)touchup:(UIButton*)click
{


    dicButtonState=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];


    if(click.selected==NO)
    {
        click.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorFromHexString:@"#ffc400"];
         click.selected=YES;



      [dicButtonState setValue:@(click.tag) forKey:@"yes"];
//        [arrButtonState addObject:btntag];

       [arrButtonState addObject:dicButtonState];

    }
#pragma mark deleting product on user deselection
    else
    {

        click.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];
        click.selected=NO;


    }

}
```

This is my code to maintain the user selection button state i am storing those values in array.

how i have to remove this ,please anybody help me to do this..

Comment: is this an array of `NSDictionaries`?

Comment: How have you created this array? Please add some code

Comment: @ZeMoon sure wait...

Comment: @ZeMoon i edited the question as per your suggestion...

Comment: Have a look at NSMutableIndexSet, it looks like a much more suitable data structure for your task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do it is to find the right dictionary and then use `[array removeObject:foundObject];`.

To find the right object, you have a few options.  The simplest is probably

```
NSDictionary *foundObject;
[array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary *d, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([d[@"yes"] isEqual:@(1)]) {
        *stop = YES;
        foundObject = d;
    }
}];

[array removeObject:foundObject];
```

This assumes that `array` is mutable.  If it isn't, wrap the code above with these lines (adjust variable names as needed):

```
NSMutableArray *array = [originalArray mutableCopy];
```

and

```
originalArray = [array copy];
```

P.S.  You can also save the index instead of a reference to the found object, and then use `[array removeObjectAtIndex:foundIndex]`.  It's a matter of preference.  For removing a single element from a smallish array, the performance characteristics are irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by **NSPredicate** if you replace **yes** flag by any other  **value**.

say,you data like this

```
NSArray *dataArray = @[@{@"value":@(0)},@{@"value":@(1)},@{@"value":@(2)},@{@"value":@(3)},@{@"value":@(4)}];
```

Then you can use NSPredicate to filter this array of dictionary.

```
NSPredicate *predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"value != %@",@(1)];
NSArray *filteredArray = [dataArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```